# Reverse background color for each cell in html table

Tags: html, css

I have an html table of unicode numbers in varying colors and I'd like to do 2 things.

1. Have the background for each cell be the reverse color of the unicode symbol color.
2. The circled numbers are not all the same size. How can I insure the same size and alignment of all symbols in the table.

Here is a sample row.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center;"><mark class="unicode" style="color: #ffbf00; font-size: 15em; font-weight: bold;">①</mark></td>
<td align="center;"><mark class="unicode" style="color: #b5c306; font-size: 15em; font-weight: bold;">②</mark></td>
<td align="center;"><mark class="unicode" style="color: #b87333; font-size: 15em; font-weight: bold;">③</mark></td>
<td align="center;"><mark class="unicode" style="color: #1560bd; font-size: 15em; font-weight: bold;">④</mark></td>
<td align="center;"><mark class="unicode" style="color: #614051; font-size: 15em; font-weight: bold;">⑤</mark></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f9sxoLnv/) is a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a different coloration to the background and the same color for the unicode to have the needed result when using `mix-blend-mode`. To have the same size, consider `monospace` as `font-family`.

You can also adjsut `padding`/`line-height` to control the spaces:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding:0 1.5em 1.5em;
}

mark {
  font-size: 20em;
  font-weight: bold;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height:0.6;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 10%;" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #ffbf00"><mark class="unicode">①</mark></td>
      <td style="background-color: #b5c306"><mark class="unicode">②</mark></td>
      <td style="background-color: #b87333;"><mark class="unicode">③</mark></td>
      <td style="background-color: #1560bd;"><mark class="unicode">④</mark></td>
      <td style="background-color: #614051"><mark class="unicode">⑤</mark></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cool didn't know about mix-blend-mode